# SSH not working and /etc/ssh folder missing

Tags: ssh

I have installed SSH on my Ubuntu 14.04 however I can't SSH into it from any other machine. There is no SSH folder under /etc so i'm guessing something went wrong with the install.

I have tried removing and re-installing but no joy.
How can I get the SSH working?

Regards

Comment: Did you install `ssh` or `ssh-server`? If you want people to connect to the computer through SSH, you need the server package.

Comment: I used the following:sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Comment: Were there any errors?

Comment: No none. Looked like it installed fine

Comment: Purge and reinstall I guess.

Comment: Yup, tried that.

Answer (score 0):

OK got it working. I simply created the folder /etc/ssh and then reinstalled the ssh server.

Odd that it could not create the folder; I was using sudo.